# question where you have to check a list of strings and every item has to be longer than the previous item

Tags: python, list, while-loop, counter, accumulate

Complete the function design for a function that takes a list of strings and determines if every string in the list is bigger than the string that comes before it. Assume that an empty list and a list with just one single element both meet the criteria (because there is no string followed by a longer string).

here is my current solution. i've tried it with a nested for loop but that didn't seem to work. i just cant figure out how to compare two items on a list with one next to the one after without going out of range

```
def growing_strings(los):
    sum=0
    counter= 0
    while len(los[counter]) < len(los[counter+1]):
            sum+=1
            counter+=1

    if sum==len(los):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without modifying your work substantially, you could include a check to your while loop that `counter+1` is less than the length of the list:

```
def growing_strings(los):
    sum=0
    counter= 0
    while counter+1 < len(los) and len(los[counter]) < len(los[counter+1]):
        sum+=1
        counter+=1

    if sum==len(los):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just check if the sorted list based on length of the string is the same as what you pass in

```
def growing_strings(los):
    return sorted(los, key=lambda x: len(x)) == los
```

if strings of the same length are not allowed, add in an extra check

```
return sorted(los, key=lambda x: len(x)) == los and len({len(x) for x in los}) == len(los)
```